# Prefixes using array in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, prefix

I'm coding a method that takes as input an array of integers and returns another array of strings, each of which denotes a non-empty prefix of the input array. For example, if the input
array is:

<3, 1, 4>

Then the output or returned array of string values should be:

<"[3]", "[3, 1]", "[3, 1, 4]">

There is an error in my code that I can't seem to find

```
public static String[] getAllPrefixes(int[] numbers) {
    String[] result = null;
    String[] arr = new String[numbers.length];   
    String seq = "" + numbers[0];
        
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {  
        arr [i] = "[" + seq + "]";  
        seq += ", " + numbers [i + 1];
    }
    
    result = arr;   
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please specify

Comment: I suggest you read the information available here [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5554734) and then think about what it means when you use your `for` loop and `i + 1` inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some problems

In this line `seq += ", " + numbers [i + 1];` when the loop is in the last item `i+1` will be out of index

When you initialized seq you added the first item in the array so in your loop you should ignore this item and start from i = 1, you should also add this item in the arr array and in your loop you should update req first then add to arr so the final code will be like this

```java
public static String[] getAllPrefixes(int[] numbers) {
    String[] result = new String[numbers.length];
    String seq = "" + numbers[0];
    result[0] = "[" + seq + "]";

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        seq += ", " + numbers[i];
        result[i] = "[" + seq + "]";
    }
    return result;
}
```

you can also use StringBuilder instance of string for appending and the code will be like

```java
public static String[] getAllPrefixes(int[] numbers) {
    String[] result = new String[numbers.length];
    StringBuilder seq = new StringBuilder("" + numbers[0]);
    result[0] = "[" + seq + "]";

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        seq.append(", ").append(numbers[i]);
        result[i] = "[" + seq + "]";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: Search for String vs StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

You must be getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, and this is because of `seq += ", " + numbers[i + 1]` line.
For example let's say length of the numbers array is 3, then your for loop will run till `i=2` in that case your `numbers[i+1]` will be `numbers[3]` which doesn't exists and it will give an exception.